# Android - How to debug callback within RxJava Subscription

Tags: android, asynchronous, junit, mockito, rx-java

I'm trying to debug the inner success callback of an RxJava Subscription object and verify certain methods inside that get called with the correct argument(s). I read up some about Captors and though maybe that's the way to go but was unable to find an example that matched my needs.

I'm unit testing with: **Mockito** and **JUnit**

```
// OrderHistoryPresenterImpl presenter;
public void loadOrderHistory(final int offset, final int limit) {
    mCompositeSubscription.add(useCase.getOrderHistory(offset, limit)
            .doOnError(throwable -> Timber.e(throwable, "Error"))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ListOfOrders>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {}

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(ListOfOrders listOfOrders) {
                    //
                    // I would like to verify the calls in this method
                    //
                    user.setTryoutCountActive(listOfOrders.getActiveTryoutsCount());

                    getView().addOrdersToView(listOfOrders);

                    mCompositeSubscription.clear();
                }
            })
    );
}
```

And here are the tests I'm trying to test it with

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OrderHistoryPresenterTest {
    // Boiler plate Dagger 2 setup + variable declarations

    private ListOfOrders response;
    private ListOfOrders spyListOfOrders;
    private OrderHistoryPresenterImpl presenter;
    @Mock private OrderHistoryUseCaseImpl useCase;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Setup + dagger 2 setup…

        response = Utils.fromJson(gson, this, "OrderHistory.json", type);
        spyListOfOrders = spy(response);

        presenter = new OrderHistoryPresenterImpl(app, useCase, user);

        when(useCase.getOrderHistory(MOCK_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN)).thenReturn(Observable.just(spyListOfOrders));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {…}

    @Test
    public void shouldGetOrderAndCall_addOrdersToView_OnActivity() {
        presenter.loadOrderHistory(MOCK_OFFSET, MOCK_LIMIT);

        // works…
        verify(useCase, times(1)).getOrderHistory(MOCK_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // This fails because it gets called right away because it's async - what to do?
        verify(view, times(1)).addOrdersToView(spyListOfOrders);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I don't know how to test the inner `Subscriber<ListOfOrders>` callback methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So if you want to test if your "Observable" works, you can use TestSubscriber and do assertions on top of it. Ref: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html. But if you want to test the Subscriber methods like onNext, then pass this guy with your `loadOrderHistory` (instead of creating a new one)  so that you can Mock this in your tests.

Comment: Checkout [RxJavaDebug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaDebug). It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say if you rewrite your method like this,

```
// OrderHistoryPresenterImpl presenter;
public void loadOrderHistory(final int offset, final int limit) {
  mCompositeSubscription.add(useCase.getOrderHistory(offset, limit)
        .doOnError(throwable -> Timber.e(throwable, "Error"))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<ListOfOrders>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {}

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {}

            @Override
            public void onNext(ListOfOrders listOfOrders) {
               load(listOfOrders)
            }
        })
   );
 }

 void loadOrders(ListOfOrders list) {
     // I would like to verify the calls in this method
     user.setTryoutCountActive(listOfOrders.getActiveTryoutsCount());

     getView().addOrdersToView(listOfOrders);

     mCompositeSubscription.clear();
 }
```

Now test this `loadOrders` method separately. Because all it cares about is getting a list of orders to process. It can come from anywhere (not only observable).

You can unit test this method now.

If you want to test Observable, then use `TestSubscriber` to see if you are actually getting a list of orders from Observable.
Ref : https://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html‌​

Comment: One problem now is that the only way I can test loadOrders is by making it public even though I would prefer to keep a method like this private. Any clean work arounds while still keeping the test files separately packaged?

Comment: Hey for testing private methods, you can use PowerMock which uses JAVA Reflection to give access. But it is generally not recommended to test private methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes